# What is the word for a "board book"?

Tags: words

Is there a common Japanese word for a board book? A board book has thick cardboard pages instead of paper pages. A board books is usually written for very young children.

(I looked in two different online dictionaries and also tried a Google search.)

Photo of a board book:

[image: board book]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the katakana loan word [ボードブック](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/keyword/%A5%DC%A1%BC%A5%C9%A5%D6%A5%C3%A5%AF):

> 本の紙が厚紙(ボード)で出来ている本のこと。幼児向けの本に多い。
>   A book with pages made of cardboard. Usually for babies.

Since they are (almost) always picture books, you could probably also use the word 絵本{えほん}, but to describe that it has thick (cardboard) pages, you can use the word 厚紙{あつがみ} like in the earlier quote. I don't think 厚紙{あつがみ}絵本{えほん} is a common word, but something like [here](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1319807848) could be used:

> **厚紙{あつがみ}のタイプの絵本{えほん}**を「ボードブック」と言います。

Google Images:

- [ボードブック](https://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=ja&site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%96%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF)
- [厚紙絵本](https://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=ja&site=imghp&tbm=isch&q=%E5%8E%9A%E7%B4%99%E7%B5%B5%E6%9C%AC)